# Grunt provide html report for mocha test

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, mocha.js

I use grunt to run my mocha test and I see the test result in the console which is OK, the problem is that this task are generating report but when you run this HTML report you just see the log of running in text...I want **to see the test aggregations** ,and the mocha unit test are run OK, what I am missing here?

```
mochaTest: {
    test: {
        options: {
            reporter: 'spec',
            colors: true,
            summery: true,
            captureFile: 'results.html', // Optionally capture the reporter output to a file
            quiet: false, // Optionally suppress output to standard out (defaults to false)
            clearRequireCache: true // Optionally clear the require cache before running tests (defaults to false)
        },
        src: ['test/*spec.js'],
        excludes: ['plugins']
    },
    'travis-cov': {
        options: {
            reporter: 'travis-cov'
        }
    }
},
```

I use the package
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-test');

https://github.com/pghalliday/grunt-mocha-test

***I want Report like this or any other nice html report which I can use...***

[image]

Comment: You can use [mochawesome](https://github.com/adamgruber/mochawesome). Change your reporter to `mochawesome` !

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH - looks nice but can you provide example how to use it in GRUNT?

Comment: Just `npm install --save-dev mochawesome` then change `reporter: 'spec',` to `reporter: 'mochawesome',`, `grunt-mocha-test` will do the rest  !

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH - Thank you , I did that install the package and run grunt with         mochaTest: {
            test: {
                options: {
                    reporter: 'mochawesome',  and nothing changed ,do I miss something else?

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH - sorry my fault :) please add it as answer and I will close it,Thank you very much!

Comment: Done ! You are welcome ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Mochawesome](https://github.com/adamgruber/mochawesome) is a custom reporter for use with the Javascript testing framework, mocha. It generates a nice HTML/CSS report that helps visualize your test suites:

First, you need to install the plugin:

```
npm install --save-dev mochawesome
```

Then you change your `grunt-mocha-test` `reporter`:

```
mochaTest: {
    test: {
        options: {
            reporter: 'mochawesome', //You need to change this !
            colors: true,
            summery: true,
            captureFile: 'results.html',
            quiet: false,
            clearRequireCache: true
        },
        src: ['test/*spec.js'],
        excludes: ['plugins']
    },
    'travis-cov': {
        options: {
            reporter: 'travis-cov'
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: I've another question which is similar please see if you can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549992/grunt-open-for-two-diffrent-files Thank you sir!