# grunt-open for two different files

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

grunt-open for two different files

I use the [grunt-open](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-open) plugin which works OK.
Now I need to open an additional file with a **different task**.
How can I do that?

I have tried:

```
  open: {
        file: {
            path: appPath + '/coverage/lcov/index.html',
            path2: appPath + '/coverage/lcov-report/index2.html'
        }
    }


 //Here I want to open first line
 grunt.registerTask('openCoverage', ['exec', 'copy', 'mocha_istanbul', 'open:path']);
 //Here I want to map second line
grunt.registerTask('MochaWeb', ['exec', 'copy', 'mochaTest', 'open:path2']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-open) it is clear that the `path` parameter holds the filepath of the file you want to open. You won't be able to add suffixed versions of "path", like `path2`. Instead, you will need to use separate [targets](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) for each file you wish to open. Your config would then look like the following:

```
open: {
    openCoverage: {
        path: appPath + '/coverage/lcov/index.html'
    },
    MochaWeb: {
        path: appPath + '/coverage/lcov-report/index2.html'
    }
}
```

Next, you will add these targets to your task definitions:

```
grunt.registerTask('openCoverage', ['exec', 'copy', 'mocha_istanbul', 'open:openCoverage']);
grunt.registerTask('MochaWeb', ['exec', 'copy', 'mochaTest', 'open:MochaWeb']);
```